# Refactoring destructuring statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const question = this.props.question
const answer = question.answer
```

Refactor the above snippet to use destructuring.

```
const { question } = this.props
const { answer } = question
```

How can I refactor this destructuring to one line?
If I do this one, `const { question : { answer } } = this.props`, I won't get the reference for `question`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reference the same property multiple times when destructuring:

```
const { question, question: { answer } } = this.props;
```

```js
const props = {
  question: {
    answer: 'answer'
  }
};
const { question, question: { answer } } = props;
console.log(question);
console.log(answer);
```